# Edit filter function on spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science, bigdata

This is my code for filtering out all the rows in the spark dataframe, the columns of which have rarely encountered values, this code is working and the number of rows really decreases (I need it for onehotencoder), but after that the dataframe itself becomes somehow strange, the usual df. Show() is executed within 2–3 minutes, and I didn't wait for the model training itself, why is that? The problems begin after this code, before that all the patches were executed quickly

```
columns_to_check = ['is_zero', 'enc_loans', 'enc_limit', 'ratio_overdue']
for column in columns_to_check:
    count_column = df.groupBy(column).agg(count("*").alias("count"))
    df = df.join(count_column, on=column, how="left")
    df = df.filter(col("count") >= 20).drop("count")

enc_paym = [i for i in df.columns if 'enc_paym' in i]
enc_zero_loans = [i for i in df.columns if 'is_zero_loans' in i]
enc_zero = [i for i in df.columns if 'is_zero' in i and 'loans' not in i]
enc_limit = [i for i in df.columns if 'pre_over' in i or 'pre_maxover' in i]
enc_loans = [i for i in df.columns if 'enc_loans' in i]
pre_loans = [i for i in df.columns if 'pre_loans' in i]
pre_since = ['pre_since_opened', 'pre_since_confirmed']
pre_tern = ['pre_pterm', 'pre_fterm']
pre_close = ['pre_till_pclose', 'pre_till_fclose']


list_of_pca = [enc_paym, enc_zero, enc_limit, enc_loans, pre_loans, enc_zero_loans, 
               pre_since, pre_tern, pre_close]

def retname(i):
  flag = 0
  for j in i:
    if 'enc_paym' in j:
      flag = 1
    elif 'is_zero_loans' in j:
      flag = 2
    elif 'pre_over' in j or 'pre_maxover' in j:
      flag = 3
    elif 'enc_loans' in j:
      flag = 4
    elif 'pre_loans' in j:
      flag = 5
    elif 'is_zero' in j and 'loans' not in j:
      flag = 6
    elif 'pre_since_opened' in j or 'pre_since_confirmed' in j:
      flag = 7
    elif 'pre_pterm' in j or 'pre_fterm' in j:
      flag = 8
    elif 'pre_till_pclose' in j or 'pre_till_fclose' in j:
      flag = 9
  if flag == 1:
    return 'enc_paym'
  elif flag == 2:
    return 'is_zero'
  elif flag == 3:
    return 'enc_limit'
  elif flag == 4:
    return 'enc_loans'
  elif flag == 5:
    return 'pre_loans'
  elif flag == 6:
    return 'ratio_overdue'
  elif flag == 7:
    return 'confirm_days'
  elif flag == 8:
    return 'open_days'
  elif flag == 9:
    return 'collection_days'

for i in list_of_pca:
  vector_enc = VectorAssembler(inputCols=i, outputCol=retname(i))
  df = vector_enc.transform(df)
  df = df.drop(*i)
```

list_of_pca = ['enc_paym', 'is_zero', 'enc_limit', 'enc_loans', 'pre_loans', 'ratio_overdue', 'confirm_days',
'open_days','collection_days']

```
pca = [PCA(k=1, inputCol=pca_col, outputCol='{0}_encoded'.format(pca_col)).fit(df) for pca_col in list_of_pca]
pipline1 = Pipeline(stages=pca)
df = pipline1.fit(df).transform(df).drop(*list_of_pca)
```

list_of_lbe = ['is_zero_encoded', 'ratio_overdue_encoded','enc_limit_encoded', 'enc_loans_encoded']

```
pca = [StringIndexer(inputCol=lbl_col, outputCol=f"{lbl_col.split('_')[0]+'_'+lbl_col.split('_')[1]}").fit(df) for lbl_col in list_of_lbe]
pipline6 = Pipeline(stages=pca)
df = pipline6.fit(df).transform(df).drop(*list_of_lbe)
```

Comment: can you share more code, and expected data?

Comment: shema must by:
root
 |-- pre_util: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pclose_flag: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- fclose_flag: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- flag: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- count_of_loans: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- enc_paym_encoded: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pre_loans_encoded: double (nullable = true)
 |-- overdue_deadlines: double (nullable = true)
 |-- is_zero: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ratio_overdue: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- enc_limit: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- enc_loans: integer (nullable = true)

Answer (score 0):

For every column applying `groupBy` & `join` data with original data frame is an expensive operation & it will take more time. Instead of that you can try below sample code (change sql query as per your logic).

```
WITH input AS (
        SELECT
            is_zero,
            enc_loans,
            enc_limit,
            ratio_overdue, (
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY is_zero) >= 20
                AND COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY enc_loans) >= 20
                AND COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY enc_limit) >= 20
                AND COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ratio_overdue) >= 20
            ) AS is_valid_count
        FROM raw_data
    )
SELECT
    is_zero,
    enc_loans,
    enc_limit,
    ratio_overdue
FROM input
WHERE is_valid_count
```

Comment: thank you, using sql is really more rational and the code itself is executed really faster, but this did not solve the problem with a very large delay in executing simple data visualization commands, show(), count() they are also executed for a very long time, although the data structure has not changed, do not tell me how it can be fixed

Comment: hum.. cool buddy ..:)